# How are «parecer», «semejante», and «similar» used to express sameness?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, sinónimos

What is the difference between different ways of expressing similarity? I see things like,

- La niña *parece* a su hermana.
- Compró dos vestidos *semejantes*.
- Quiere una fiesta de cumpleaños *similar* a la de su hermano mayor.
- Son *parecidos* como dos gotas de agua.

English doesn't have obvious analogs to *parecer* or *semejante* in this context. Where would you use one or another of these words?

Answer (score 5):

> La niña **SE** parece a su hermana.
>   **El/Ella/Mi Papa/Un Alien/Juan** compró dos vestidos semejantes/parecidos.
>   **Brian** quiere una fiesta de cumpleaños similar/parecida a la de su hermano mayor.
>   **Luis y Juan** son parecidos como dos gotas de agua.
>
> The girl looks like her sister.
>   She bought two similar dresses
>   Brian wants a party just as his older brother's
>   Luis and Juan are such a pair of water drops

Parecer (Verb):
seem
appear
look
look like

Semejante (Adjective):
such
similar
like
alike

Similar (Adjective):
similar
parallel